# Automating WooCommerce order emails along with shipping labels to warehouse

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I am wondering (have never used Woocommerce before) something about the order flow with WC.

I'm looking at administrating the backend of the site where Woocommerce and Wordpress are, and would like to find a way to automate the orders via email to the warehouse/shipping department which is in another location.

I don't really want them to have access to the backend, as they don't understand it/have never used it.

Ideally would love to also include the (Canada Post) shipping labels to be sent along with the order email notifications.

(orders come into woocommerce > emails are sent forwarding orders to warehouse for processing/shipment)

Is there a way for me to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

To send an email in Blind Carbon Copy (BCC) to the warehouse/shipping department on Processing order email notification, you will use this custom hooked function:

```
// Add a custom hidden email to processing email notification
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'warehouse_shipping_email_notification', 20, 3 );
function warehouse_shipping_email_notification( $header, $email_id, $order ) {
    // Only for customer processing order notification
    if( 'customer_processing_order' != $email_id ) return $header;

    // HERE below set the warehouse/shipping name and email address
    $name = 'Macfilish Warehouse Shipping';
    $email = 'shipping@macfilish.com';

    // Add warehouse email to BCC
    $header .= 'Bcc: ' . utf8_decode($name . ' <' . $email . '>') . "\r\n";

    return $header;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> As I have never used Woocommerce Canada Post extension, I could not give you any help to include shipping labels…

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!